Enhance i18n config with option for the property "load"
With Composable Storefront (Spartacus) 2211.19.0, and i18next 23.7.6, we have the problem, that i18n translation files are loaded multiple times.
This is caused by the i18next option load which has a default value of all.
For countries having languages like en_GB, it loads the language file en_GB and en.
Please enhance the Spartacus i18n config with the property load so that we can set it's value to currentOnly.
This could be done by adjusting the class I18nextHttpBackendInitializer and the method initialize:
initialize(): InitOptions<HttpBackendOptions> {
    this.i18next.use(i18nextHttpBackend);
    return { 
        ...this.getConfig() // new method to return general configs for i18n
        backend: this.getBackendConfig(); 
    };
  }

Even more flexibility would be given, if we could just define an object with several i18next options, then we can define any additionally needed properties for i18next.
